Sending a message to a user by Serverless Azure SignalR triggered functions and storing a payload to an Azure storage account table simultaneously
I have the following C# code that sends a message to a user:
[Function(nameof(SendToUser))]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "chat", ConnectionStringSetting = "SignalRConnection")]
public static SignalRMessageAction SendToUser([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    using var bodyReader = new StreamReader(req.Body);
    return new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage")
    {
        Arguments = new[] { bodyReader.ReadToEnd() },
        UserId = "userToSend",
    };
}

I'd also like to save an object's json payload to an Azure Storage Account's table when this signalR function is triggered using output table binding instead of azure storage account's SDK. Is it feasible to combine SignalROutput with TableOutput and make the code above look like the following pattern?
public class MyTableData : Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
}

[Function(nameof(SendToUser))]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "chat", ConnectionStringSetting = "SignalRConnection")]
[TableOutput("OutputTable", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
public static object[] SendToUser([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    using var bodyReader = new StreamReader(req.Body);
    return
    [
    new SignalRMessageAction("newMessage")
    {
        Arguments = new[] { bodyReader.ReadToEnd() },
        UserId = "userToSend",
    },
    new MyTableData()
    {
       Text = "Test text",
       PartitionKey = "key",
       RowKey = "myrowkey",
       Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
       ETag = "tag"
    }
    ];
}

